# View PDF in Preview in Full Screen?

Tags: pdf, preview

Is there any way to view a PDF in Preview in Full Screen? Quick Look works, but it doesn't have the 'remembering the page you were looking at' feature that I like.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`View` > `Slideshow` (or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>).

Comment: This is great but you can't zoom in or out using  + or  -.

Comment: @JFW: Indeed, it appears [this was removed in Snow Leopard](http://discussions.apple.com/message.jspa?messageID=11383768).

Comment: Your best bet is  + f to switch between “Actual Size” and Fit To Screen. (works while you’re in “slideshow” mode)

Comment: Isn't  + f 'Find'?

Comment: @JFW: Not while you're in Slideshow mode. There it resizes to "Fit to screen", but not back to "Actual size". You can also do it with the on-screen button bar.

Answer (score 2):

Install [MegaZoomer](http://osx.iusethis.com/app/megazoomer), it'll give you nice fullscreen viewing in Preview.

Update: Note that OS X Lion will give you this feature.

Comment: Or use [Skim](http://skim-app.sourceforge.net/) instead. It's an excellent pdf viewer, much more feature rich than preview. And it's free.

Comment: Cool, nice find.

Answer (score 0):

ctrl+cmd+f

by using this combination, you can also zoom in pages in fullscreen.